# The regression analysis below relates US annual energy consumption in trillions of BTUs to

Tags: statistics

The regression analysis below relates US annual energy consumption in trillions of BTUs to the independent variable "US Gross Domestic Product (GDP) in trillions of dollars."   Which of the following is the lowest level at which the independent variable is significant?

[image]

A 0.94

B  0.10

C  0.05

D  0.01

please help

Comment: Please don't post homework questions here without at least explaining your current thoughts. Do you know what statistical significance is and how it relates to P-values (there's a hint)?

Comment: because of p-value is 0.0000
I think The lowest level at which the independent variable is significant is 0.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment is correct, adel, but you should make sure you're getting the p-value from the correct place (as there are basically 3 p-values listed, all of which have value of 0.0000).

The question is also oddly phrased - what this test is really doing is saying whether the coefficient for the independent variable in the regression formula is statistically significantly different from 0. The question gets at the spirit of this, but isn't really the right phrasing.

Regardless, from output like this you look at the chart at the bottom. If you want to know if the coefficient of the independent variable is different from zero, look at the independent variable line - in this case, the very bottom one labeled "GDP ($trillions)". This line tells you (from left to right) the following:

a) In the regression formula, the coefficient of this variable is 3,786. That effectively means that for every increase of $1 trillion in GDP, energy consumption goes up by 3,786 trillion BTUs

b) The std. error of this coefficient is 220

c) The test statistics is 17.19

d) The p-value (i.e. the probability of the coefficient actually equaling zero) is 0.0000

Given that, if you've chosen a significance level of pretty much anything, you would conclude that the coefficient is not equal to zero and therefore, in the language of the question, that the independent variable is significant.

If, by contrast, that last p-value was .027, then the independent variable would be significant at a .05 level, but not at a .01 level.

Always remember to pick your significance level first, though! Not after you calculate the p-values.